# phpMyadmin Error sql syntax

Tags: phpmyadmin

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE  summertraining.student(

studentID VARCHAR( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
Name VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
KSUEmail VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
PhoneNo VARCHAR( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
coordinatorName VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL ,
supervisorName VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL ,
GPA DOUBLE( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
password VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
registerFlag VARCHAR( 7 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  studentID )
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL, `password` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, `registerFlag` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,' at line 1 strong text

Answer (score 0):

The error is in line:

```
GPA DOUBLE( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
```

Need to use:

```
GPA DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
```

Comment: I don't think this is true...double(4) just assigns the size of the double type; it should be valid SQL

Comment: thank to you serg ..finally its work i thought i should put size x]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed the `DOUBLE(4)` part as @Serg pointed out. If you want to specify a precision for a double value, there need to be at least two numbers to specify the precision, not only one. From the MySQL manual:

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.

However, you may just want to just stick with `DOUBLE` because this syntax is specific to MySQL:

> For maximum portability, code requiring storage of approximate numeric data values should use FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION with no specification of precision or number of digits.

Here's the link to the relevant page in the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html